# Conky's frame appears randomly

Tags: unity, conky

I tweaked the Harmattan Texture conky to create a mix between the comfortable version and the god-mode version. The problem is that at some moments, which I can not anticipate, a black frame, or shadow, appears arround my conky.

[image: With and without the frame]

I noticed as well this morning that the time appeared not in the center but on the top-right corner. I opened the conkyrc file, saved it twice to refresh it, and the time was back in the center. I don't know whether these two things are linked or not.

And here is my conkyrc file

```
# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
imlib_cache_size 10

# Window specifications #
gap_x 20
gap_y 100
minimum_size 268 450
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type override  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
default_shade_color AAAAAA
draw_outline no
default_outline_color AAAAAA
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_graph_size 26 80
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Droid Sans:size=10
text_buffer_size 256
override_utf8_locale yes

# Useful shortenings #
short_units yes
pad_percents 2
top_name_width 7

# Color scheme #
default_color F9F9F9
color1 F9F9F9
color2 F9F9F9
color3 F9F9F9
color4 F9F9F9
color5 DCDCDC
color6 F9F9F9
color7 F9F9F9
color8 F9F9F9

TEXT
# Various images #
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=603413&u=c" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/shadow.png -p 6,12 -s 256x367}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-photos-8/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 20,25 -s 228x229}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/photo-filter.png -p 20,25 -s 228x229}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/top-bg.png -p 20,25 -s 228x66}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/bottom-bg.png -p 20,254 -s 228x110}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/border.png -p 20,25 -s 228x339}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/separator-v.png -p 95,270 -s 1x83}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/separator-v.png -p 172,270 -s 1x83}\
\
# The name of days #
\
${color2}${voffset 268}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${color2}${voffset -17}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${color2}${voffset -17}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
\
# Temperatures #
\
${color2}${voffset 53}${alignc 77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1'}°
${color2}${voffset -17}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°
${color2}${voffset -17}${alignc -77}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°/${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°
\
# Weather conditions section #
\
${color1}${font Droid Sans:size=48}${goto 32}${voffset -204}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°${font}\
${color2}${alignr 54}${voffset -90}${execi 300 grep "yweather:atmosphere" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "humidity=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} %
${color2}${alignr 54}${voffset 20}${execi 300 grep "yweather:wind" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} ${execi 300 grep "yweather:units" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "speed=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}
${color2}${alignr 54}${voffset 20}${execi 300 grep "yweather:astronomy" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "sunrise=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}
${color2}${alignr 54}${voffset 20}${execi 300 grep "yweather:astronomy" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "sunset=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}
${color1}${font Droid Sans :size=12}${goto 46}${voffset -14}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "text=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${font}\
\
# Clock + calendar #
\
${voffset -194}${font Droid Sans Mono :size=22}${alignc}${color2}${time %H:%M}${font}${color}
${voffset 4}${font Droid Sans :size=10}${alignc}${color6}${time %A, %d %B}${font}${color}
\
# Variousecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 118,296 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weath images including the forecast icons #
\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/humidity.png -p 224,108 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/wind-2.png -p 224,145 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/sunrise.png -p 224,182 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.conky-weather/assets/Texture/Comfortable/sunset.png -p 224,219 -s 16x16}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1').png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 42,296 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 118,296 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather/icons/weather-icons-light/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 194,296 -s 32x32}${font}\
```

I would like to permanently keep this frame, and even, if it is possible, to change its colour but I have no idea how to do it and don't understand the reason for this strange behavior.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved my problem thanks to this [page from noobslab.](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/03/solutions-to-fix-black-shadow-of-conky.html)

I didn't try the compiz solution but changed

```
own_window_type override
```

to

```
own_window_type dock
```

and adapted gap_x (the conky was out my screen with the new setting). Since it looks to work great and to be perfectly stable.